# Logical error in getting a text from URL with okHttp

Tags: android, android-asynctask, okhttp

Im trying to write an app to read a text file from an url like this "http://chemvaaj.xzn.ir/test/words.txt"
it seems right but it doesn't return what it should :\

here's my code :

```
   public  String DL (){
    OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler();
     String text ="";
    try {
        text = handler.execute().get();


        if (text!= null && text.length()> 0){

            System.out.println("not empty");

            return text;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
            text= "empty !!";
    }
    return text;
}
```

and here is `OkHttpHandler` class :

```
public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

private final String DB_URL = "http://chemvaaj.xzn.ir/test/words.txt";

OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
    builder.url(DB_URL);

    Request request = builder.build();

    try {

        Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    Log.e("ANSWER", "" + s);
}
}
```

and here's my logcat after call DL() function :

`10-28 00:23:25.167  17288-17288/erfan.bagheri.chemvaaj E/ANSWER﹕ com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RealResponseBody@423bc6b8`

Comment: Why calling `get()` method?

Comment: get() method waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `return response.body().toString();` by `return response.body().string();`

Please refer to my following working sample code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        new GetFileRequest().execute();
    }
...
private class GetFileRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://chemvaaj.xzn.ir/test/words.txt")
                        .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                return response.body().string();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (mTextView != null && result != null) {
                mTextView.setText(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: BNK's screenshot]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please check how an `AsyncTask` works. [Here's the official](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), easy to understand how-to-use.

Then you'll find that the method `execute()` returns the task itself, not the resulting `String` object.

It seems that `OkHttpClient`'s returned `Response` object can be transformed to string in the following way:

`response.body().toString();`

Just one more hint: please avoid returning null in any method, it's considered very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

OkHttpClient is used in the wrong way(Suppose you want to use async). OkHttp is a full featured Http client library and has Asynchronous requests implemented in itself.
So there is no need to Android AsyncTask.

Here is the right way:

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://chemvaaj.xzn.ir/test/words.txt")
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

      @Override public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

        System.out.println(response.body().string());
      }

      @Override public void onFailure(Request request, Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
      }
});
```

Comment: @BNK Thats exactly what I was trying to say:)

Comment: I just commented for your following idea "OkHttpClient is used in the wrong way" :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with OkHttpClient but from the log I am guessing that the body response is a complex object that does not have a toString() that will show you a human readable response. You will probably have to print a specific member of that object to get your readable response.

Answer (score 0):

try this

OkHttpClient and callback:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
                    .build();



            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

//                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
//                    for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {
//                        System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
//                    }
//                    System.out.println(response.body().string());

                    InputStream in = response.body().byteStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String result, line = reader.readLine();
                    result = line;
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line;
                    }
                    System.out.println(result);


                }
            });
```